# IF statements within a loop to trigger custom email and subject line

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a working code that sends email alerts whenever a contract expiry date reaches 90 days from today's date, 60 days, 30 days, and same day-expiry. The subject line at the moment does not say the status (..is expiring in 30 days) but that statement is in the body of the email. If I wanted that statement to also show in the subject line, how do I go about revising the codes?

SAMPLE (status as of the moment)

SUBJECT: (TEST) ALERT: C1PH TPM Contract FFMIRAVITE INC with Contract # 41501

EMAIL: , , with contract name , and contract number  will expire in 30 days.

```
for (var i = 0; i < duedates.length; i++) {
if (duedates[i] == formattedCurrentDate) {
  sendEmail(i + 2, sheetquery, " is Expired as of today."); 
}

else if (duedates[i] == formattedThirtyDaysFromNow) {
  sendEmail(i + 2, sheetquery, " will expire in 30 days.");
}

else if (duedates[i] == formattedSixtyDaysFromNow) {
  sendEmail(i + 2, sheetquery, " will expire in 60 days.");
}

else if (duedates[i] == formattedNinetyDaysFromNow) {
  sendEmail(i + 2, sheetquery, " will expire in 90 days.");
}

}
}


function sendEmail(rowIndex, sheetquery, isExpiringToday) {
  var thirdparty = sheetquery.getRange(rowIndex, 3).getValue();
  var contracttype = sheetquery.getRange(rowIndex, 4).getValue();
  var contractnumber = sheetquery.getRange(rowIndex, 6).getValue();
  var contractname = sheetquery.getRange(rowIndex, 7).getValue();
  var recipientsTO = "myemail@gmail.com";
  var subject = "(TEST) ALERT: C1PH TPM Contract" + " " + thirdparty  + " with Contract # " +   contractnumber;
  var message = thirdparty + ", " + contracttype + ", " + "with contract name " + contractname +
            ", and contract number " + contractnumber + isExpiringToday;
```

GmailApp.sendEmail(recipientsTO, subject, message);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to append it the end of the subject variable. Did you try this?

```
  var subject = "(TEST) ALERT: C1PH TPM Contract" + " " + thirdparty  + " with Contract # " +   contractnumber + " " + isExpiringToday;
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! That worked perfectly without revising the entire script!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code and article might help you.

```
    function checkAndSendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Contracts");
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = dataRange.getValues();

var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

var thirtyDaysFromNow = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var sixtyDaysFromNow = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + (60 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var ninetyDaysFromNow = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
var row = data[i];
var contractExpiryDate = new Date(row[2]); // Assuming expiry date is in column 3
contractExpiryDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

var subjectLineAddon = "";

if (contractExpiryDate.getTime() === ninetyDaysFromNow.getTime()) {
  subjectLineAddon = " will expire in 90 days";
} else if (contractExpiryDate.getTime() === sixtyDaysFromNow.getTime()) {
  subjectLineAddon = " will expire in 60 days";
} else if (contractExpiryDate.getTime() === thirtyDaysFromNow.getTime()) {
  subjectLineAddon = " will expire in 30 days";
} else if (contractExpiryDate.getTime() === currentDate.getTime()) {
 subjectLineAddon = " is Expired as of today";
}

  if (subjectLineAddon !== "") {
    var emailSubject = "ALERT: " + row[1] + " Contract" + subjectLineAddon; // Assuming contract name is in column 2
    sendCustomEmail(row[3], emailSubject, row[4]); // Assuming email is in column 4 and message in column 5
  }
}
}

function sendCustomEmail(email, subject, message) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
```

[Enhancing Email Alerts in Google Apps Script with Dynamic Subject Lines](https://www.tempmail.us.com/en/google-apps-script/enhancing-email-alerts-in-google-apps-script-with-dynamic-subject-lines)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Thank you! I bet this also works if I was willing to revise my code. The article is exactly about this scenario (contract email alerts) which was written on the same day! how lovely

Comment: Please confirm to stackoverflow that I have answered your question correctly. Thank you